# Storing number larger than INT_MAX in an int

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

Can someone explain this C++ behaviour to me?

```
for (int i=0;i<3;++i){
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

If I input a number larger than INT_MAX (like 124124124124124) only ONCE, this outputs:

```
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
```

My best guess is that it recognizes my input is a number, but it slices because `x` can only fit up to `2147483647`. What I don't understand is why after inputting that big number only ONCE, the input "overflows" to the other inputs, and prints `2147483647` three times, then ends the program.

Comment: The first read puts the stream into an error state and the subsequent reads do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stream extraction operator `>>` notes that you can't stream in that large number and sets the `fail` bit, and *does not modify* the value of `x`.

Subsequent reading from that input stream (`cin` in this case) fail immediately, and thus the value of `x` remains unchanged (and in this case, undefined).

Comment: And, of course, the reason it's repeating the value three times is because `i < 3`. Change it to any number and it repeats that number of times.